# Live view an html document in emacs

Tags: html, previewing

Running emacs 25.2.2.

Here is something (apparently) simple I want to do, but am unable to:

- I am editing an html document. I want to see the same document in the
  internal browser in a vertically split window.
- Now, if I make any changes to my html document and hit a key (may be, save buffer could be the trigger), the
  browser buffer is updated to reflect the changes.
- The scrolling between the two buffers is synchronized

I can `C-c C-v (browse-url-of-buffer)` but that does not help because there is no way of updating the browser buffer. Moreover, the scrolling is not synchronized.

How do I get this done?

Comment: If you have access to the `w3m` executable, then there is a complimentary Lisp library that can help you view an html file like a web-browser (within Emacs) -- although, not as fancy as Firefox and so forth.  Another library (which I believe is all Lisp and does not require an executable) is called `shr` -- I've only used it once and am by no means an expert.  Although I love to do everything in Emacs, if you are doing any sort of web development, then you will want to do a `start-process` or the equivalent thereof and use the real browser that your target audience will be using.

Comment: In terms of a live-preview (e.g., via the `post-command-hook`), there will undoubtedly be a significant trade-off in terms of performance in Emacs because the working buffer will need to be rendered every command loop and updated in the target buffer.  The slow-down in performance is probably a deal-breaker, but maybe you'll have good luck ...  Perhaps after every save would be a better way to do it ...  [Personally, I rsync a draft to the shared server and view the live draft version in an external web browser.]

Comment: @lawlist Your point about the live preview is well-taken. I have updated the question.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, because it doesn't discuss scrolling, but the answers on this question may help: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/476/how-to-make-emacs-render-html-without-having-to-save-the-file

Answer (score 5):

Live preview of Markdown in Emacs is discussed in the terrific [Guide to Markdown Mode for Emacs](https://leanpub.com/markdown-mode/read#leanpub-auto-live-preview-mode) and also at the [Emacs wiki](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Markdown#Live_preview_as_you_type).

The [markdown-preview-eww](https://github.com/niku/markdown-preview-eww) package will use Emacs' build-in `eww` browser to preview Markdown in a separate pane within Emacs:

[image: Live Markdown preview in Emacs]

A few other solutions will auto-refresh external web browsers as one types, notably [Impatient Mode](https://github.com/skeeto/impatient-mode) and [Livedown](https://github.com/shime/emacs-livedown). If none of those help then see the [Guide to Markdown Mode for Emacs](https://leanpub.com/markdown-mode/read#leanpub-auto-live-preview-mode) or [Emacs wiki Markdown](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Markdown#Live_preview_as_you_type) guides for alternative options.